# ASP.NET MVC C# DisplayFormat Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm going straight to the point here.

I'm trying to display the `Monthly Income` to have 2 decimal only.

I've tried using `DisplayFormat` however it doesn't work when I add it on Textbox.

**Model**

```
public class AgentModel
{

    [Display(Name = "Monthly Income")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal MonthlyIncome { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
//this input display the two decimal
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MonthlyIncome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

//this one display 5 decimal
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MonthlyIncome, new { @class = "form-control"})
```

I'm confused what is the difference between the two inputs.
I'm using the `DataFormat` because I want the format to be centralized on my model. and to not use this code `@string.Format("{0:N2}",decimal.Round(agent.MonthlyIncome, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))` to limit the decimal places. since I'll be doing this in all of my views if this is what I do.

I've also tried to just output the value of `monthly income`

```
<td>@agent.MonthlyIncome</td>
```

this still returns 5 decimal places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To display a formatted value using `TextBoxFor()`, use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<code>2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B</code>0%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B<code>0,</code>1%7D%7D,System.String,System.Object%29)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MonthlyIncome, "{0:0.00}", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

The 2nd parameter is the format string. Note that the `DisplayFormatAttribute` is only respected when using `EditorFor()` or `DisplayFor()`

Note also that `<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MonthlyIncome)</td>` will render the value with the correct format.

Comment: I see...,  so I need to add the format parameter on every views that I have? where as if I use the EditorFor it'll automatically add the dataanotation on my model..

Comment: If you want to use `TextBoxFor()`, then yes. But is there a reason you do not want to use `EditorFor()` - the 2 implementations in your question will generate identical html.

Comment: Hi steph.. I'm going to use `EditorFor` since it is efficient when it comes to editing the format of the textbox.... however, how can I display the format of the `MonthlyIncome` if I tried to add this on my table liek this `<td>@agent.MonthlyIncome</td>` coz it will still display 5 decimal places unlike when using`EditorFor` it'll convert it to textbox and convert the display?

Comment: See the last paragraph of my answer

Comment: how about when I loop the data... and I got a bunch of `monthlyIncome`?

Comment: I assume you have worked it out, but `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].MonthlyIncome) }` or `foreach(var item in Model) { @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.MonthlyIncome) }`

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayFormat` only works with `EditorFor/DisplayFor`. Look at [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fA3oX2) fiddle for mvc.

**Model**

using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

```
namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class SampleViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [MinLength(10)]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        [Display(Name = "Ask Magic 8 Ball any question:")]
        public string Question { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public decimal MonthlyIncome { get; set; }

        //See here for list of answers
        public string Answer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var s = new SampleViewModel();
            s.MonthlyIncome = 1000;
            return View(s);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetAnswer(string question)
        {               
            int index = _rnd.Next(_db.Count);
            var answer = _db[index];
            return Json(answer);
        }

        private static Random _rnd = new Random();

        private static List<string> _db = new List<string> { "Yes", "No", "Definitely, yes", "I don't know", "Looks like, yes"} ;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.SampleViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

        <!-- CSS Includes -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <style type="text/css">

            .field-validation-error {
                color: #ff0000;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1>Hello Stranger</h1>

                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Question)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Question, new {@class="form-control"}) 
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question)
                    </div>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MonthlyIncome)

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success submit">Ask</button>
                }

                <br/><br/>
                <div class="alert alert-warning fade">
                    <img src="http://entechprod.blob.core.windows.net/dotnetfiddle/morpheus.jpg" style="max-width:100%;"/><br/><br/>
                    <strong><span class="alert-content"></span></strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- JS includes -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function openAlert(txt) {
                $('.alert-content').text(txt);
                $('.alert').addClass('in');
            }

            function closeAlert() {
                $('.alert').removeClass('in');
            }

            $(function(){
                var answer = '@Model.Answer';

                if(answer && answer != '') 
                    openAlert(answer);

                $('#Question').change(closeAlert);
                $('#Question').keyup(closeAlert);

                $('.submit').click(function(){
                    if($('form').valid()) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="GetAnswer", controller="Home"})',
                            data: {Answer: '', Question: $('#Question').val()},
                                type: 'POST',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                success: function(resp) {
                                openAlert(resp);
                        }});
                    }
                    else {
                        closeAlert();
                    }
                });

            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```